# IntelliJ & Angular2 / TypeScript - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/...'

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, angular

There seems to be alot of questions and answers about this problem but so far most answers I have found have been for Windows / Visual Studio. I'm using OSX and IntelliJ for a Angular2 with TypeScript project I am working on and I am currently getting warnings / errors (those little red squiggly lines) under the "from" locations when I import from the angular2 library, for example in my app.ts I have:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/angular2/ts/typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
/// <reference path="node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>

import { bootstrap } from "angular2/platform/browser";
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
```

All 3 import statements have warnings under the from locations (where we have "angular2/...."). I tried to correct this by editiing the typescript-compiler.xml in Intellij:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="TypeScriptCompiler">
    <option name="isCompilerEnabled" value="true" />
    <option name="typeScriptServiceDirectory" value="$USER_HOME$/node_modules/typescript/bin" />
    <option name="typeScriptCompilerParams" value="-m amd -t ES5" />
    <option name="versionType" value="SERVICE_DIRECTORY" />
  </component>
</project>
```

All other modules I import are fine (like the components I write myself) but those I import from Angular2 have the warning? Has anyone managed to over come this error / problem as I've been trying for a while now to remove the problem. I currently have Version 1.7.5 of TypeScript installed.

Please note that I have no `typings.json` file or `npm typings` installed in my `dev-dependancies`.

This is my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "files": [
    // there is an array of files here
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "app/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": true
  }
}
```

and this is my tslint.json file:

```
{
  "rules": {
   "align": [true,
        "parameters",
        "arguments",
        "statements"],
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [true, "check-space"],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "indent": [true, "spaces"],
    "interface-name": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "label-undefined": true,
    "jsdoc-format": true,
    "max-line-length": [true, 80],
    "member-ordering": [true,
        "public-before-private",
        "static-before-instance",
        "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-key": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-require-imports": true,
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-comma": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-unreachable": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "one-line": [true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "quotemark": [true, "single"],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": true,
    "sort-object-literal-keys": false,
    "triple-equals": [true, "allow-null-check"],
    "typedef": [true,
        "call-signature",
        "parameter",
        "property-declaration",
        "variable-declaration",
        "member-variable-declaration"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [true, {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
    }],
    "variable-name": [true,
      "allow-leading-underscore"],
    "whitespace": [true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Angular 2 did you use?

Comment: "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.16"

Comment: Upgrading to beta.17 makes no difference

Answer (score 3):

For me it was fixed by using relative paths, i.e. (depending on the location of your `.ts` file):

`///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>`

Also, in your Intellij Settings make sure to enable "Use tsconfig.json".
My settings file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="TypeScriptCompiler">
    <option name="isCompilerEnabled" value="true" />
    <option name="typeScriptCompilerParams" value="--module &quot;amd&quot; --target &quot;ES5&quot; --experimentalDecorators" />
    <option name="useConfig" value="true" />
  </component>
</project>
```

---

**Please also note thate since a few hours `angular2 rc.1` was released** (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3229bf16656749427d1def38ced0e1d1d2ae1fa4/CHANGELOG.md)

This introduces some breaking changes regarding how to import modules (e.g. "angular/core" gets "@angular/core").

You don't need the `///<reference path=".."/>` stuff anymore if you are using the rc version. System.js automatically finds the corresponding `index.d.ts` in the node_modules directory (if set up correctly: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/systemjs.config.js)

I also had to change the target to `ES6` otherwise I got error messages that e.g. `Map` or `Promise` was undefined. If you still want to keep the `ES5` target you need to include `es6-shim` (.js and .d.ts)